# how to call a variable from another class in bluJay

Tags: java, class, variables

i have this code:

```
public class Barrier
{
    private Car myCar;
    private Sensor mySensor;
    private Card myCard;

public Barrier()
{
    myCar = new Car();
    mySensor = new Sensor();
    myCard = new Card();
}
}
```

and this code

```
public class Card
{
    private int Card1;

public void get_no_card(int result)
{   
    Card1 = result; 
}

public void display()
{
    if (Card1 == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("Card is present");
    }
}
```

i want to call the variable Card1 from the Card class into the Barrier class, so that the barrier class can output Card is present as well as the card class, how do i go about this?

Comment: you change your `get_no_card` method name to `setCard1`. Then write a `getCard1()` that returns `Card1`. and call with `myCard.getCard1();` or `myCard.display()` in `Barrier` somewhere

Comment: okay ill give it a try thanks :)

Comment: The class of an object can be retrieved by calling getClass() on that object. i.e. `myCard.getClass()`

Comment: its giving me an error: cannot find symbol variable Card1 in barrier.

Comment: you have your myCard istance field in Barrier class. you need to first set the value of Card1 in the Card object with setCard1(). and then call display();. But you make the calls on the Card object. Is that clearer? I can give you a working example later if no one beats me to it.

Comment: okay thatll be great thanks :)

Comment: Well *and* you should respect the Java Naming Conventions: field names should **never** start with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand you correctly.
First the Barrier class:

```
public class Barrier {
     private Car myCar;
     private Sensor mySensor;
     private Card myCard;

    public Barrier() {
        myCar = new Car();
        mySensor = new Sensor();
        myCard = new Card();
    }

    public void callCard() {
        myCard.setCard1(1);
        myCard.display();   
        System.out.println("The class type of myCard is " + myCard.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

And the Card class:

```
public class Card {

    private int Card1;

    public void display() {
        if (getCard1() == 1) {
             System.out.println("Card is present");
        }
    }

    public int getCard1() {
        return Card1;
    }

    public void setCard1(int card1) {
        Card1 = card1;
    }   
}
```

And test it:

```
class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
         Barrier b = new Barrier();
         b.callCard();
    }
}
```

So when we call the `callCard()` method we first set the value of `Card1` to 1 so that `display()` will print the text. Then we print the name of the class type of myCard.